# Javascript code not running well on IE9

Tags: javascript, html

I have code which is supposed to display an ad for 10 seconds, then load a embed code.
It is working fine on Firefox, but on IE9 it runs the ad and the embed code in the same time in the background.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nbsec = 10;
    var c = 0;
    var t;
    var timer_is_on = 0;
    var sum = 0;

    function timedCount()
    {
        c = c + 1;
        t = setTimeout("timedCount()", 1000);
        sum = nbsec - c;
        document.getElementById('chrono').innerHTML = "<br>Loading .. Please wait " + sum + "secondes";

        if(c == nbsec) {
            stopCount();
            document.getElementById('mypub').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('mygame').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('mygame').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('mygame').style.height = 'auto';
            document.getElementById('mypub').style.height = '0px';
            document.getElementById('mypub').style.padding = '0px';
            document.getElementById('mypub').innerHTML = "";
        }
    }

    function stopCount()
    {
        clearTimeout(t);
        timer_is_on = 0;
    }
</script>

<table border="2" align="center" color="F2FC7E">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="mypub" style="visibility: visible; text-align:center; padding:20px;"> 

                <script>
                    ..............
                </script>

                <div id="chrono" style="color:#FFF;"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="mygame" style="visibility: hidden;display:none; height:0px">
                <param name="initial_focus" value="true">
                <applet>
                    ........................
                </applet>   
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    timedCount();
</script>
```

Is there is anyway to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please remove all the backticks from your code and indent the code whole block by four spaces. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: FYI: Your use of attributes to style a table is outdated and you really should use css classes to change styles instead of doing them one by one. Also it is bad practice to have the same `document.getElementById('mypub')` pasted over and over again, use a variable.

Comment: t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000); i dont think it should have quotation around to function name

Comment: yes, there is a way. debug it

Comment: If you're setting 'mypub' to hidden, why do you continue operating on the node by changing height, padding, innerHTML...

Comment: Probably... we're expensive, though.

Comment: please write something only if you have the answer for my question, Thank you.

Comment: Heh, doesn't really work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nbsec = 10;
function timedCount() {
    document.getElementById('chrono').innerHTML = "<br>Loading .. Please wait " + nbsec + "secondes";
    if( nbsec ){ // if sum != 0, wait call again
        setTimeout( timedCount, 1000 ); 
        nbsec--; // counter
    } else { // do after 10 sec
        document.getElementById('mygame').style.cssText = "visibility:visible;display:block;height:auto;";
        document.getElementById('mypub').style.cssText="visibility:hidden;height:0px;padding:0px;";
        document.getElementById('mypub').innerHTML = "";
    }
}
// stopCount is not needed
// start counter
timedCount();
</script>
```

that`s about logic